# How to get the count of occurrence in the given string in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code as below

```
class usermaincode(object):
   @classmethod
   def word_occur(cls,input1)
```

I need to wrap the code with the above code.
Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

```
input1 = "Hello new new"
```

Output should be `{"Hello":1,"new":2}`.

Comment: Have you even tried to do this? What was the problem?

Comment: take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Please look at this function https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-12.php

Answer (score 2):

Here's easiest way, using Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

class usermaincode(object):
  @classmethod
     def word_occur(cls,input1)
         _input = input1.split(' ')
         return dict(Counter(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
class usermaincode(object):
   @classmethod
   def word_occur(cls,input1):
      words = input1.split(" ")
      unique_words = set(words)
      output_dict = dict()
      for word in unique_words:
          output_dict[word] = words.count(word)
      return output_dict
```